# R: Efficiently locating time series segments with maximal cross-correlation to input segment?

Tags: r, time-series, subset, correlation

I have a long numerical time series data of approximately 200,000 rows (lets call it **Z**).

In a loop, I subset **x** (about 30) consecutive rows from **Z** at a time and treat them as the query point **q**.

I want to locate within **Z** the **y** (~300) most correlated *time series segments* of length **x** (most correlated with **q**).

What is an efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below finds the 300 segments you are looking for and runs in 8 seconds on my none too powerful Windows laptop, so it should be fast enough for your purposes.

First, it constructs a 30-by-199971 matrix (`Zmat`), whose columns contain all of the length-30 "time series segments" you want to examine. A single call to `cor()`, operating on the vector `q` and the matrix `Zmat`, then calculates all of the desired correlation coefficients. Finally, the resultant vector is examined to identify the 300 sequences having the highest correlation coefficients.

```
# Simulate data
nZ <- 200000
nq <- 30
Z <- rnorm(nZ)
q <- seq_len(nq)

# From Z, construct a 30 by 199971 matrix, in which each column is a
# "time series segment". Column 1 contains observations 1:30, column 2
# contains observations 2:31, and so on through the end of the series.
Zmat <- sapply(seq_len(nZ - nq + 1),  
               FUN = function(X) Z[seq(from = X, length.out = nq)])

# Calculate the correlation of q with every column/"time series segment.
Cors <- cor(q, Zmat)

# Extract the starting position of the 300 most highly correlated segments    
ids <- order(Cors, decreasing=TRUE)[1:300]

# Maybe try something like the following to confirm that you have
# selected the most highly correlated segments.
hist(Cors, breaks=100)
hist(Cors[ids], col="red", add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Nice solution. `x` should be `q` in the `cor` call (and perhaps `q` should be assigned `Z[seq_len(qlen)]`. In keeping with the Mike's terminology, `qlen` = `x`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I've now revised the code, changing the variable names, and adding some more comments/explanation. Not sure whether `q` should necessarily be the first 30 elements of `Z`, so I haven't changed that bit. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The naive solution is indeed very slow 
(at least several minutes -- I am not patient enough):

```
library(zoo)
n <- 2e5
k <- 30
z <- rnorm(n)
x <- rnorm(k) # We do not use the fact that x is a part of z
rollapply(z, k, function(u) cor(u,x), align="left")
```

You can compute the correlation by hand, from the first moments and comoments, but it still takes several minutes.

```
y <- zoo(rnorm(n), 1:n)
x <- rnorm(k)
exy <- exx <- eyy <- ex <- ey <- zoo( rep(0,n), 1:n )
for(i in 1:k) {
  cat(i, "\n")
  exy <- exy + lag(y,i-1) * x[i]
  ey  <- ey  + lag(y,i-1) 
  eyy <- eyy + lag(y,i-1)^2 
  ex  <- ex  + x[i]    # Constant time series
  exx <- exx + x[i]^2  # Constant time series
}
exy <- exy/k
ex <- ex/k
ey <- ey/k
exx <- exx/k
eyy <- eyy/k
covxy <- exy - ex * ey
vx <- exx - ex^2
vy <- eyy - ey^2
corxy <- covxy / sqrt( vx * vy )
```

Once you have the time series of the correlations, 
it is easy to extract the position of the top 300.

```
i <- order(corxy, decreasing=TRUE)[1:300]
corxy[i]
```