# R: Is there a fast approximate correlation library for large time series?

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to make a software that will, in real time, find the top N correlated time series windows (to a query series).

There are approximately 5000 windows, each 34 rows in length. With respect to the query series I need the 300 most correlated windows.

Currently I am using the `cor` function, but it is proving to be entirely way too slow. I need response times under a second. Under 250ms would be great, but anything in that vicinity would do.

Is there a "fast approximate correlation" library for R that I can use to reduce the size of my large "contestant list" (the 5000 windows)?

If not, is there another method to shrink this list somewhat?

Here is the function that I am running:

```
GetTopN<-function(n)
{ 
  Rprof()

  x<- LastBars()
  x<-as.data.frame(cbind(x[-1,1],diff(x[,2])))

  colnames(x)<-c('RPos','M1')
  actionlist<-GetFiltered()
  print(nrow(actionlist))
  crs<-mat.or.vec(nrow(actionlist),2) #will hold correlations  


  for(i in 1:nrow(actionlist))
  {

       crs[i,2]<-cor(z[actionlist$RPos[i]+n1,2],x[,2])  
  }

  crs[,1]<-actionlist$OpenTime
  sorted <- crs[order(crs[,2], decreasing=T),1:2] 
  topx<- head(sorted,n)
  bottomx <- tail(sorted,n)
  rownames(bottomx)<-NULL
  DF<-as.data.frame(rbind(topx,bottomx),row.names=NULL ) 
  colnames(DF)<-c('ptime','weight')  
  sqlSave(channel,dat=DF,tablename='ReducedList',append=F,rownames=F,safer=F) 
  FillActionList()
  Rprof(NULL)
  summaryRprof()  
}
```

And here is the output from `summaryRprof`:

```
$by.self
              self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
[.data.frame       0.68    25.37       0.98     36.57
.Call              0.22     8.21       0.22      8.21
cor                0.16     5.97       2.30     85.82
is.data.frame      0.14     5.22       1.26     47.01
[                  0.14     5.22       1.12     41.79
stopifnot          0.14     5.22       0.30     11.19
sys.call           0.14     5.22       0.18      6.72
GetTopN            0.12     4.48       2.68    100.00
eval               0.10     3.73       0.46     17.16
deparse            0.10     3.73       0.34     12.69
%in%               0.10     3.73       0.22      8.21
$                  0.10     3.73       0.10      3.73
c                  0.08     2.99       0.08      2.99
.deparseOpts       0.06     2.24       0.14      5.22
formals            0.06     2.24       0.08      2.99
pmatch             0.06     2.24       0.08      2.99
names              0.06     2.24       0.06      2.24
match              0.04     1.49       0.12      4.48
sys.parent         0.04     1.49       0.04      1.49
match.arg          0.02     0.75       0.58     21.64
length             0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75
matrix             0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75
mode               0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75
order              0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75
parent.frame       0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75
sys.function       0.02     0.75       0.02      0.75

$by.total
              total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
GetTopN             2.68    100.00      0.12     4.48
cor                 2.30     85.82      0.16     5.97
is.data.frame       1.26     47.01      0.14     5.22
[                   1.12     41.79      0.14     5.22
[.data.frame        0.98     36.57      0.68    25.37
match.arg           0.58     21.64      0.02     0.75
eval                0.46     17.16      0.10     3.73
deparse             0.34     12.69      0.10     3.73
stopifnot           0.30     11.19      0.14     5.22
.Call               0.22      8.21      0.22     8.21
%in%                0.22      8.21      0.10     3.73
sqlQuery            0.20      7.46      0.00     0.00
sys.call            0.18      6.72      0.14     5.22
odbcQuery           0.18      6.72      0.00     0.00
GetFiltered         0.16      5.97      0.00     0.00
match.call          0.16      5.97      0.00     0.00
.deparseOpts        0.14      5.22      0.06     2.24
match               0.12      4.48      0.04     1.49
$                   0.10      3.73      0.10     3.73
c                   0.08      2.99      0.08     2.99
formals             0.08      2.99      0.06     2.24
pmatch              0.08      2.99      0.06     2.24
names               0.06      2.24      0.06     2.24
sys.parent          0.04      1.49      0.04     1.49
LastBars            0.04      1.49      0.00     0.00
length              0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
matrix              0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
mode                0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
order               0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
parent.frame        0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
sys.function        0.02      0.75      0.02     0.75
mat.or.vec          0.02      0.75      0.00     0.00
odbcFetchRows       0.02      0.75      0.00     0.00
odbcUpdate          0.02      0.75      0.00     0.00
sqlGetResults       0.02      0.75      0.00     0.00
sqlSave             0.02      0.75      0.00     0.00
sqlwrite            0.02      0.75      0.00     0.00

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 2.68
```

Looking at the `summaryRprofs` output it seems that perhaps `[.data.frame` takes the longest. I do not see how to get around that though.

Comment: What does your data look like? Using `cor` to calculate the highest 300 correlation coefficients for a 34 by **50k** matrix and a 34-element vector takes 30ms. Correlating against a 34 by 5000 matrix registers 0 on `system.time`. The correlation for the query vector against the 30 by 199971 matrix created [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9145989/489704) takes ~180ms

Comment: Have you profiled your code and checked that most of the time was indeed spent in the `cor` function? Which [linear algebra library](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Linear-algebra) are you using? Have you tried to parallelize your code (some linear algebra libraries do that for you)?

Comment: I am just using the stats library. I have not attempted to parallelize it.

Comment: 85% of the time is spent in the `cor` function, but only 8% actually computing the correlation (in `.Call`): most of the time is spend in "book-keeping tasks" (checking the arguments, reformatting the data, looking for missing values, etc.). If you manage to skip all this processing and directly call `.Internal(cor(...))`, you should be able to achieve a significant speed up.

Comment: Another potential (easier) speed up would be to get rid of the loop in which you call `cor`: if the function seems slow, it is probably because it is called many, many times.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! I will look into getting rid of the loop. I have `n1` defined as `n1<-seq(-32,0)` perhaps that is why the "book-keeping" tasks are so slow? How can I get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vincent points out in comments, computing (Pearson) correlation is itself pretty quick.  Once you exhausted the basic R profiling and speeding up tricks, you can always go

- multicore and/or parallel via appropriate R packages
- use compiled code, and I can think of a package to facilitate that
- even consider GPUs as e.g. my Intro to High-Performance Computing with R slides (on my [presentations page](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/presentations.html)) contained an example of computing the (more expensive Kendall) correlation for a large gain