# R: How to speed up this function?

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a large data frame (named **z**) that looks like this:

```
    RPos    M1
    1   -0.00020
    2   0.00010
    3   -0.00012
    4   -0.00035
    5   -0.00038 
...etc (about 300,000 observations)
```

It is essentially a time series (although it is *actually* a data frame, not `ts` or `zoo`).
Where RPos is the index number (explicitly stored), and M1 is any metric.

I have another data frame (named **actionlist**) with about 30,000 *non-consecutive observations. Each value in actionlist's RPos column represents the last of 34 consecutive points.

My final piece of data is a single data frame (named **x**) of only 34 consecutive observations.

My goal is to calculate the correlation coefficients between **x** and each observation in actionlist (which, again, is the end-point of 34 consecutive observations).

To do this I must generate these 34-point consecutive point time series segments from **z** (the large data frame).

Currently, I am doing it like this:

```
n1<-33:0
for(i in 1:nrow(actionlist))
{
    crs[i,2]<-cor(z[actionlist$RPos[i]+n1,2],x[,2])  
}
```

When looking at the `Rprof` readout this is what I get:

```
$by.self
              self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
[.data.frame       0.68    25.37       0.98     36.57
.Call              0.22     8.21       0.22      8.21
cor                0.16     5.97       2.30     85.82
...etc
```

It looks as though `[.data.frame` is taking the longest.
Specifically I am pretty sure that it is this part:
`z[actionlist$RPos[i]+n1,2]`

How can I speed up (eliminate the need for?) this part of the function?

I asked a similar question before, except instead of looking within a restricted list (`actionlist`) I was looking through every possible consecutive 34-observation within **z**. The answer was posted [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107791/r-efficiently-locating-time-series-segments-with-maximal-cross-correlation-to-i) but I cannot figure out how to adapt it to a restricted list.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you post some reproducible code and test data.

Comment: Also, it would be easier (for me especially!) if you used the same terminology in this as in the previous answer. And is there any reason you need `z` and `x` to be data.frames?? It's very wasteful to repeatedly subset things you don't need to, so for instance, you could easily take `x[,2]` outside of the loop, by doing `x2 <- x[,2]` once outside, and then referring to that vector in the loop as `x2`. Likewise, indexing using `$Rpos[i]` isn't needed at all if `Rpos` itself just runs from `1:nrow(z)`...

Comment: Yeah you are definitely right, in the future I will use consistent terminology. I'll keep the subsetting thing in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward is probably to build
a matrix containing the data you want 
to compute the correlation with, and eschew the loop altogether.

```
# Sample data
n <- 3e5
m <- 3e4
k <- 35
z <- data.frame(
  RPos = 1:n,
  M1   = rnorm(n)
)
actionlist <- sample( k:n, m )
x <- rnorm(k)

system.time( for (j in 1:10) {
  # Index of the observations we want
  i <- sapply( (k-1):0, function(u) actionlist - u )
  # Data we want to compute the correlation with
  y <- matrix( z$M1[i], nr=nrow(i) )
  # Computations
  result <- cor(t(y),x)
} ) # 150ms per iteration
```

Comment: Excellent! That sped things up a ton. Thanks a lot!